# Windows Forms Logins

Tags: c#, windows, forms

When I use the following code, if the user name and password are same, it is working fine, if I provide wrong username and password it is nether giving me message or logging in:

```
 private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = Helper.getconnection();
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select SupportName, Password from Logins where SupportName='" + txtSupportName.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'", con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
                string Name = txtSupportName.Text;
                string Pwd = txtPassword.Text;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if ((dr["SupportName"].ToString() == Name) && (dr["Password"].ToString() == Pwd))
                    {
                       // MessageBox.Show("welcome");
                        Form Support = new Support();
                        Support.ShowDialog();

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("SupportName and password are invalid");
                }
            }

            dr.Close();

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        if (txtSupportName.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value to Support Name!");
            txtSupportName.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (txtPassword.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value to Description!");
            txtPassword.Focus();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code? If so what happens. If not, why not?

Comment: Your while loop is executing? if you are checking username and password in the query, what is the point of checking it again in the while loop? If it is incorrect, will you get any rows?

Comment: FYI, your code isn't protected against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)! Use parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: put break points in the while loop and observe whats happening?? see if its slipping down to else part..check the variables state..

Comment: If I enter the wrong user name and password, I want it to display the message "SupportName and password are invalid", but here nothing happens, it is idle even though I entered wrong details.

Comment: Karthik, try `MessageBox.Show(this,"message");` is your messagebox behind another window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Kelly has written a good answer I just implement it and add separate methods to segregate responsibility

```
private bool Login(string supportName, string password)
{
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(supportName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
   {
      throw new ArgumentException();
   }

   using(var connection = Helper.getconnection())
   using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
      conmmand.CommandText = "SELECT 1 FROM Logins WHERE SupportName=@SupportName AND Password=@Password";
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupportName", supportName);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);

      return command.ExecuteScalar() != null;
   }
}

private void ShowSupportForm()
{
   var supportName = txtSupportName.Text;
   var password = txtPassword.Text;

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(supportName))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value to Support Name!");
      txtSupportName.Focus();
      return;
   }

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value to Passwod!");
      txtPassword.Focus();
      return;
   }

   if(Login(supportName, password))
   {
      using(var form = new Support())
      {
         form.ShowDialog(this);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("SupportName and password are invalid");
   }
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowSupportForm();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I will use the code you provided, all you have helped me work with the code, I will be always grateful to you.

Answer (score 5):

There seem to be a few issues with your code:

1. You should validate your inputs before running the query
2. You should parameterize your queries (there are lots of samples on SO) instead of using string concatenation
3. You seem to be assuming you will get a result from your SQL query. You should maybe check `dr.HasRows` to see if the details are correct, or check if `dr.Read()` returns true to determine whether to display the message box or not
4. You should dispose of your DB objects using `using` blocks. E.g. (not sure why formatting isn't working):

   using (SqlConnection con = Helper.getconnection())
   {
       ...
   }

instead of calling `Dispose` and `Close` explicitly. Even if you do want to call `Dispose` and `Close` explicitly you should do so in a `finally` block.

Comment: Link to [Little Bobby Tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png) is missing!

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in you code. You forgot to check if data reader has any row or not.

```
if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if ((dr["SupportName"].ToString() == Name) && (dr["Password"].ToString() == Pwd))
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("welcome");
                Form Support = new Support();
                Support.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SupportName and password are invalid");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SupportName and password are invalid");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add `HasRows` to check if your username and password exist on your table / it retrieve data on your database.

```
if(dr.HasRows)
{
  //username and password exists

  while (dr.Read())
        {
            if ((dr["SupportName"].ToString() == Name) && (dr["Password"].ToString() == Pwd))
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("welcome");
                Form Support = new Support();
                Support.ShowDialog();
            }

        }
}
else
{
//username and password not exists

MessageBox.Show("SupportName and password are invalid");

}
```

Best Regards